# Arduino and Android over Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android, arduino, wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I created the kettle controlled over Wi-Fi. I used Wi_fi module ESP8266, Arduino , water sensor, relay and temperature sensor. Kettle works fine at first start, so everything I have in code for Arduino works properly. Only problem is when i need to get data to Android app over Wi-Fi. I used AsyncTask client in the application and sometimes i can't connect to my kettle or when I want to get actual temperature it goes well for example for 20°C but then the actuall temperature stucks there. When this occurs I re-open the app connect again and then it works again. The kettle switches off correctly so the android is sending right data only the connection between ESP8266 and Android app is a bit buggy. Is there ony other possibility to establish communication between ESP and Android to send right data for full cycle ?

```
#include <OneWire.h>       
OneWire  ds(9);             
int nPinWaterState = 8;     
int nPinRelayState = 7;          
byte addr[8];              
bool bRelay=false;           
bool bWater=true;           
int nTemp=0;            
int nFinishTemp=-1;    
void setup()
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);                                     
  InitDS18B20();                                          
  pinMode(nPinWaterState, INPUT);                          
  pinMode(nPinRelayState, OUTPUT);                              
  digitalWrite(nPinRelayState,HIGH);                           

  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",1000);                            
  sendData("AT+CWSAP=\"Kettle\",\"123\",3,0\r\n",200);   
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",200);                        
  sendData("AT+CIPAP=\"192.168.0.100\"\r\n",200);         
  sendData("AT+CWDHCP=0,1\r\n",200);                      
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",200);                        
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,8888\r\n",200);                
 }    
void loop()
{
  ReadSensors();                                                    
  if(!bWater || nTemp>=nFinishTemp)                           
  {
     bRelay=false;
  }

  if(Serial.available())                                            
  {
    if(Serial.find((char*)"+IPD,"))                                 
{

 String strRead =Serial.readStringUntil('\n');                  
 int connectionId=strRead[0]-48;                                

 if(Serial.find((char*)"AND:"))                                 
 {                                  
   strRead=Serial.readStringUntil('\n');                        
   nFinishTemp=strRead.substring(1,4).toInt();              
   if(strRead[0]=='T')                                          
   {
      if(bWater && nTemp<nFinishTemp)                     
      {
        bRelay=true;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      bZap=false;
   }
 }
```

this string I send to Android device

```
    String strSend = "KET:";
    if(bRelay) 
{
strSend=strSend+'T';
}                                                              
         else
         {
            strSend=strSend+'F';
         }

 if(bWater)                                               
 {
    strSend=strSend+'T';
 }
 else
 {
    strSend=strSend+'F';
 }

 char strTemp[3];
 sprintf (strTemp, "%03d",nTemp);                 
 strSend=strSend+strTemp;
 String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
 cipSend += connectionId;
 cipSend += ",";
 cipSend +=strSend.length();
 cipSend +="\r\n";

 sendData(cipSend,20);
 sendData(strSend,20);
 String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
 closeCommand+=connectionId;                           
 closeCommand+="\r\n";
 sendData(closeCommand,20); 
}
}

   if (bRelay)                                               
   {
     digitalWrite(nPinRelayState,LOW);
   }
   else
   {
     digitalWrite(nPinRelayState,HIGH);      
   } 
}
    String sendData(String command, const int timeout)
{
    String response = "";
    Serial.print(command);                                                                             
    long int time = millis();
    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {                                             
    char c = Serial.read();                     
    response+=c;
  }  
}
return response;
}
void ReadSensors(void)
{                                    
  float tempC;
  tempC=ReadDS18B20();
  nTemp=(int)tempC;                                                 
  bWater = !digitalRead(nPinWaterState); 
}
```

and lastly the DS18B20 temp sensor work

```
    void InitDS18B20(void)
{

if ( !ds.search(addr)) {

ds.reset_search();
delay(100);
return;
  }

  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {

      return;
  }
}
float ReadDS18B20(void)
{
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;                                          
  byte data[12];
  float celsius;

  ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);  
  ds.write(0x44, 1);                        

  delay(100);                              


  present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);    
  ds.write(0xBE);                          

  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {               
  data[i] = ds.read();
  }
  int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];

  byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);

  if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;         
  else if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3;   
  else if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1;    


  celsius = (float)raw / 16.0;
  return(celsius);
}
```

As I said everything in whole code work as I wanted only that WiFi module sometimes stops sending the temperature to the Android app. Any solutions ?

Comment: How many times a second is this trying to send data to your phone?

Comment: Actually i really dont know that ... Why u asking ? U think the ESP is trying to send too fast ?

Comment: I misread the code.  How often is your android device asking for the data?

Comment: I can post here the Android code, but I think it is asking every second because I used normal Handler and Runnable. This calls client.java where i read data from Arduino using AsyncTask. I don't know if it helps but if u want i will post here java code too.

Comment: I have a DS18B20 that measures the temperature of my keezer.  Sometimes it takes a whole second to retrieve the data.  Mine does not cache the address like yours so I'm sure that mine has more delay than yours, but that timing delay stacking up across requests could be a cause.  I only request once and let the user refresh, so I don't have a problem with the timing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need much IO pins and you can redesign your hardware, then rewrite everything into `ESP8266`. Thus avoid sending AT commands and a communication can  be easily debugged. It can be done in `Arduino IDE` with [ESP8266 Arduino Core](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.3.0/)

Comment: I found this article [link](http://web-engineering.info/node/52) I will try that . It works with ESP8266 library